# TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type Map)

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython

How do I correctly define `__repr__` for my map class?

```
class map(object):
    """Find data folders that could be imported and return as list"""
    def __init__(self,height=400,zoom=0):
        """Initialize the map"""
        if zoom == 0:
            z = get_map_zoom()
        else:
            z = zoom
        self.map = Map(center=get_map_center(), zoom=z)
        self.map.layout.height = f'{height}px'
    def __repr__(self):
        return self.map
    def add_layer(self,tableName:str,style_name='default',geomColumn:str = 'geom'):
        """Get GeoJSON data from database and add as layer to map"""
        data = db.execute(f'SELECT ST_AsGeojson(ST_Transform({geomColumn},4326)) from {tableName} order by random() limit 5000;')
        style = get_style(style_name)
        geo_json = GeoJSON(style=style,data={'type': "FeatureCollection", 'features': [json.loads(row[0]) for row in data]})
        self.map.add_layer(geo_json)
```

From Jupyter I am generating the map like this:

```
from modules import map
m = map.map()

m.add_layer('geo.service_area','service_area')
m.add_layer('rawgeo.ways',geomColumn='the_geom')

display(m)
```

But `TypeError: __repr__ returned non-string (type Map)` error occurs on `display(m)`.

I am able to make it work if I use `display(m.map)` instead.

Comment: How about `return repr(self.map)` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `__repr__` method must return a string. From [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__repr__) (some emphasis mine):

> `object.__repr__(self)`
>
> Called by the repr() built-in function to compute the “official” string representation of an object. If at all possible, this should look like a valid Python expression that could be used to recreate an object with the same value (given an appropriate environment). If this is not possible, a string of the form <...some useful description...> should be returned. **The return value must be a string object**. If a class defines `__repr__()` but not `__str__()`, then `__repr__()` is also used when an “informal” string representation of instances of that class is required.

**Edit**: As @khelwood suggests you can `return repr(self.map)` in the `__repr__` method.